# stop child page reloading on additional clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child

when a button is clicked a child window is opened. Then if it is clicked again it reloads that page. I am trying to avoid this from happening even if the parent page is reloaded. As long as the child page 'test' is open I want a condition in the click event to do nothing to the child window and alert a warning. Is this possible? Thanks

```
$('#send').click(function(){

   if(*child page already open*){
    alert('already open');
 }else{
        window.open("test.html","Ratting","width=550,height=170,0,status=0,");
      }
});
```

Comment: thanks all for the code. These work fine unless the parent page is reloaded. is there a way to get it to work if the parent page is reloaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to test that child window *exists* **and** is *still open*:

```
var childWindow;

$('#send').click(function(){
    if (childWindow && !childWindow.closed) {
        alert('already open');
    } else {
        childWindow = window.open("test.html","Ratting","width=550,height=170,0,status=0,");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var childPage = null;
$('#send').click(function(){
  if(childPage && !childPage.closed){
    alert('already open');
  } else{
    childPage = window.open("test.html","Ratting","width=550,height=170,0,status=0,");
  }
});
```